# Is there a way to disable slide over in ipad (ios 9)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios9, drawer

Is there any way to disable slider over in my app as in ipad(ios 9) from right side my custom drawer is opening and sometimes slide over comes up instead of opening app drawer.

Please help.

Comment: i am not talking about opening my app in slider over. i just wanted to ask that if its possible to disable slide over while my application is active (running).